# sqlite changing a value using joins

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, join

I have a table called:

```
Recipes
name  |  key
abc   |  2
```

And a second table called:

```
Monday
cell_id  |  recipe_id  |  recipe_name
4        |             |  abc
```

How do I set the recipe_id column in monday with the key value from the other table where the name and recipe name in both tables are the same? I'm using sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to look up the key value corresponding to the name:

```
UPDATE Monday
SET recipe_id = (SELECT key
                 FROM Recipes
                 WHERE name = Monday.recipe_name)
```